# How to go to next view controller if i am at last page of uicollection view. its horizontal transition and paging is enable

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
}

@IBAction func onBackButtonTap(_ sender: Any) {
    //    if collection view is on first page i have to pop  
    // self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    let collectionBounds = self.collectionView.bounds
    let contentOffset = CGFloat(floor(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x - collectionBounds.size.width))
    self.moveCollectionToFrame(contentOffset: contentOffset)

}

@IBAction func onNextButtonTap(_ sender: Any) {
    // if collection view is on last page i have to push to another view controller 
    let collectionBounds = self.collectionView.bounds
    let contentOffset = CGFloat(floor(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x + collectionBounds.size.width))
    self.moveCollectionToFrame(contentOffset: contentOffset)

}

func moveCollectionToFrame(contentOffset : CGFloat) {
    let frame: CGRect = CGRect(x : contentOffset ,y : self.collectionView.contentOffset.y ,width : self.collectionView.frame.width,height : self.collectionView.frame.height)
    self.collectionView.scrollRectToVisible(frame, animated: true)
}
```

How to go to next view controller if I am at last page of UICollectionView? Its horizontal transition and paging is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the current visible index and check if it is the last or first cell. And based on that you can take your action of pushing or popping the view controller

```
  var currentIndexPath:IndexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.last!

        if currentIndexPath.row == yourArray.count - 1 {
            print("last row, we'll push")
        }

        if currentIndexPath.row == 0 {
            print("first row, we'll pop")
        }
```